# HTML vertical alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I don't seem to find the right solution for vertically aligning things. Here is the piece of markup I'm using (note: I'm using Angular and hence `{{something}}` is replaced with the correct text):

```
<td style="width:55%;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
    <font size="3" color="#0B3861">
        <label style="max-width:150px;background:#BDBDBD;border-radius:15px;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis"
               title="{{Legend}}"
               dir="auto">
            <b>
                {{Legend}}
            </b>
        </label>
    </font>
    <span type="button" 
          ng-model="Notifs"
          ng-click="Present_Notifications()"
          style="background:green;padding:0 4px 0 4px;cursor:pointer;margin:0 0 10px 10px;height:50px">
        <font size="2" color="white">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"> </i>
        </font>
    </span>
</td>
```

What I get is:

[image: Wrong vertical alignment of icon at the right of the legend]

The green box with the white flag should be vertically align (**middle**) with the legend (John Smith...).

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use this `margin: 10px;` instead of `margin: 0 0 10px 10px;`

Comment: Nope. This does not solve the issue.

Comment: I believe this could be of use http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to `label` tag and it should look properly.

Please see the [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/2937/).

Comment: It is strange (because what is NOT vertically aligned is what follows the label)... but this addition did the trick. Thanks @AlexM for your quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

i run it within `<!DOCTYPE html>` on Chrome, it ok.
You can show all the table tags